# Fill twitter button with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter

is it possible to create a twitter-button , while clicking a link? :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gmq39/22/

I tried with:

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
```

The "button", which appear´s has no functionlaity and style´s

Anybody know´s a workaround or what do i need to inlcude? need your help.. greetings!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `twttr.widgets.load();` to bind the twitter functionality to a dynamically added button.

Also, to make sure you don't load the script over and over again, you could first check if the script is already loaded with something like this

```
function twitter() {
    if ($(".twitter-follow-button").length > 0) {
        if (typeof (twttr) != 'undefined') {
            twttr.widgets.load();
        } else {
            $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
        }
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('body').html('<a href="https://twitter.com/MagnusEngdal" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @MagnusEngdal</a>')
    twitter();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/23D8C/1/

Comment: could you show an example for usage in my case? creating object´s with this?

Comment: yes, i read about this function but only in context with a tweet-share/tweet-button , but is this possible to do the same with a follow-button? greetings, edit: thanks for the jsfiddle, but i am not sure how to do this for a follow-button :/

Comment: Updated my answer and link with follow instead of share

Comment: yea looks great, is it possible to put this follow-button in a modalbox like in my example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gmq39/22/ and load the data from the link(a-tag) in the button? greetings